# Find least amount of combinations in multi-dimensional array (php). (Need help with school assignment)

Tags: algorithms

I’ve got a computer science school assignment which I can’t solve for the past week and it’s driving me crazy!
I hope I’m posting this on the right board.

I need to find the least amount of combinations in “not-so complex” data in php. The answer of course doesn’t have to be in php. Anything helps!

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:**

We need to transport items with least possible vehicles.

There is a multi-dimensional array of items, each has assigned possible vehicles for transport and how much % the item occupies in that vehicle. I need to fit these items in as few vehicles as possible. We can’t fit more items in vehicle if they exceed 100%.

The array looks like this:

```
$items = [
    item1 => [
        vehicle1 => 50,
        vehicle2 => 30,
        vehicle3 => 60
        ],
    item2 => [
        vehicle2 => 60,
        ],
    item3 => [
        vehicle1 => 40,
        vehicle3 => 60,
        ]
]
```

So in the example above, just by looking at it, we can see we are going to need 2 vehicles.
item1 + item3 can go with vehcle1 only, because they don’t fit in vehicle3 (it would exceed 100%). Item2 can go only with vehicle2 only.The result in this example is at least 2 vehicles.

The data I wrote here as example is not static. To test my algorithm, there is going to be different data, so I can’t hardcore anything.

The answer doesn’t need to be specifically in php. If you have any idea how to solve this, anything will be huge help for me!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, the problem you've posed is quite similar to the well known Knapsack problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Have a look at some definitions and solutions to that problem to get some inspiration.

Secondly, I would like to point you in the direction of greedy algorithms (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms/). Often the simplest solution yields fairly good results and could provide some further insight on how to achieve the optimal solution (if it is not already).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Seems like it could help me a bunch, or at least send me in a right direction.